# xcode present segue on restful callback (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, segue

I am self taught Swift user and trying to do something simple but it's got me pretty stumped.  I have a simple registration form.  After submitting the items for registration, I want to move the page to a "how it works" page via a segue, but ONLY when my restful API returns success.  Here's what I have so far; feel free to send me a better way to do this as well.  All criticisms are welcome.

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string:"http://www.example.com/scripts/Register.php")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let postString = "email=\(email)&password=\(pass)"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
    data, response, error in

    if (error != nil) {
        println("Error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    var err: NSError?
    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
    var showTutorial : Bool = false

    if let parseJSON = json {
        var returnValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
        println("Status: \(returnValue)")

        var isUserRegistered: Bool = false
        if (returnValue == "Success") {
            showTutorial = true
        } else if (returnValue == "Error") {                    
            // handle error
        }
    }

    // if successful registration, show how it works page
    if (showTutorial) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("howItWorksSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

I have a segue named `howItWorksSegue` attached to this view controller going to the `HowItWorksViewController`.  I'm receiving this error from Xcode:

> 2015-10-12 21:22:43.261 ZiftDine[11396:2307755] Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374
>   2015-10-12 21:22:43.391 ZiftDine[11396:2307755] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything done with UI should be done on the main thread, try wrapping you performSegue call like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("howItWorksSegue", sender: self)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually just tried it and it worked.  Still wondering if this is a good method for this though.

Comment: It's exactly the right method for this :) I use it very often. If it answered your question then please mark as answered

Comment: @Swinny89 thanks for sharing this - I'm just starting out with swift and this has made my life a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

@Swinny89 gave the solution to your problem but some explanation is in order.

If you read the description of `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:`, which is the method you are using (although your Swift code uses trailing closure syntax to drop the `completionHandler` label and put the closure outside the parentheses) it says:

> completionHandler: The completion handler to call when the load
>   request is complete. This handler is executed on the delegate queue.

Then if you read the description of the init method `sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:` it says:

> queue: A queue for scheduling the delegate calls and completion
>   handlers. If nil, the session creates a serial operation queue for
>   performing all delegate method calls and completion handler calls.

Serial operation queues run on a different thread.

So, taking all of those pieces of information together, it means that your completion closure is going to be executed on a thread other than the main thread.

A cardinal rule of iOS/Mac development is that you must do all UI calls from the main thread. If a call changes anything on the screen, it's a UI call.

Your code is invoking `performSegueWithIdentifier:` from a background thread. It changes what's displayed on the screen, so it must be a UI call. Therefore it needs to be run on the main thread.

The GCD function `dispatch_async()`, with a queue of `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, submits a closure to be run on the main dispatch queue, a queue that runs on the main thread.

So Swinny's solution fixes your problem.

The take-away here:

Any time you are running code in a closure, stop and think: "Am I positive that this closure will always be run on the main thread?" If the answer is no, enclose the code in a call to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`, like Swinny's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answers by @Duncan C and @Swinny89 are good. For anyone coming in from Google, the syntax in Swift 3 has changed a little:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("howItWorksSegue", sender: self)
})
```